# How and which value to set for supplyDelta in the rebase function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens, defi

This is my rebase contract https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xE6A61396361935231E6BC403Fc206Fa1A99E628F#contracts. I want to set a rebase time period of 4h but I don't know how to set the supplyDelta paramter in the rebase function. Also where can we set the add and remove rate

> rebase(uint256 epoch, int256 supplyDelta). Can someone explain how will I be able to achieve this?

Comment: I also want to know. I am in dire need. In rebase, what numbers do you put in write's epoch (uint256) and supplyDelta (int256)?

Comment: @mzaidi Did you write that contract?

Answer (score 0):

when I was in need to reabse the price, Then, i wrote my own rebase contract(PriceOracle) and setup a azure worker to call rebase method after specific time. becuase in at contract level you can't setup auto call after a specific time. you have to call method at require time.